# Staged a protest vs staged a protest rally?

Tags: collocations

Let's say, you read an article a few minutes ago... and it indicated:

> ''Members of different militant groups in XXX City **staged a protest rally** on Wednesday to express their support for the embattled X senator.''

Is **''staged a protest''** is already enough to say a group is protesting against something, what is this **staged a protest rally**? This seems redundant to me...

Comment: It seems like you are asking what "rally" means or adds to the example. Dictionary research should be added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, saying "staged a protest" does show that they were protesting against something, but "protest rally" specifies that they were protesting in the form of a rally, rather than a strike or another means of voicing opinion.

Comment: I agree with you, but it might help to explain what sorts of *protests* you can *stage* that are not *rallies*.

Comment: Agreed. There are also non-protest types of rallies.  In the context of the quote, it is clear that they are not only supporting the senator but also protesting about something.